# Nested loops or function application

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, data-science

I have 2 sets of latitude/longitude coordinates, 4 arrays total. My goal was to find the distance between one group (airbnb_coord) and the closest member of the second group (station_coord). I've written an nested for loop to accomplish this

```
shortest_distance = make_array()
for air_lat, air_long in zip(airbnb_coord[0],airbnb_coord[1]):
    for stat_lat, stat_long in zip(station_coord[0],station_coord[1]):
        distances = make_array()
        distances = np.append(distances, np.sqrt(((air_lat-stat_lat)**2)+((air_long-stat_long)**2)))
        shortest_distance = np.append(shortest_distance, min(distances))
```

The problem is, airbnb_coord is 40,000 long, and station_coord is 500 long. This has been running for more than an hour now.

Can someone tell me if there is a better way? I'm pretty weak at function application, but I'm sure there is a strategy that uses such.

Comment: Please show us an input and (expected) output for a small sample of the coordinates.

Comment: Is this something you will need to run more than once? If not, an unoptimized program such as this is fine.  Just let it run for however long it takes. (Though I do recommend using something like `tqdm` so you know its progress and expected time to complete). If you need to run it more than once, then you will want to optimize it.  I don't have any experience with this, but I have watched this video which was pretty relevant to this topic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJxEcs0w_kE It isn't in python, but the principles remain the same.

Comment: So, given all AirBnB-to-station pairs, you want the shortest? This seems like a bipartite variation on [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), which in general has sub-quadratic algorithms. Being bipartite, there may be an even more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Just for some intuition, if AirBnB-A is "between" AirBnB-B and Station-A, then AirBnB-B/Station-A cannot be the answer.

Comment: What about creating a voronoi diagram around each station. Then the nearest station to each airbnb will be whichever voronoi shape it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the time significantly if you don't calculate the minimum in `distances` each iteration

```
shortest_distance = make_array()
for air_lat, air_long in zip(airbnb_coord[0],airbnb_coord[1]):
    min_distance = np.sqrt(((air_lat-station_coord[0][0])**2)+((air_long-station_coord[0][0])**2))
    for stat_lat, stat_long in zip(station_coord[0], station_coord[1]):
        distance = np.sqrt(((air_lat-stat_lat)**2)+((air_long-stat_long)**2))
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance

    shortest_distance = np.append(shortest_distance, min_distance)
```